# Another way to write this code without using lamba. Only printing even numbers from a list

Tags: python, list, lambda

I am very new to python and just wondering how to rewrite this code without using lambda so I get a better understanding of solving problems in different ways.

I want to print out only even numbers from this list:

```
my_list = [1, 5, 4, 6, 8, 11, 3, 12]

new_list = list(filter(lambda x: (x%2 == 0) , my_list))

print(new_list)

ouput: [4,6,8,12]
```

Comment: Hi Rebecca, welcome to StackOverflow. I'll note that this question may not be the best fit for this site which aims more to have questions with concrete answers and this one is more soliciting a range of opinions. A good place for it might be [on the code review stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What were the results of your research into alternatives to lambdas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new_list = [x for x in my_list if x%2==0]
```

I believe this should work, if you don't like list comprehension, then I suggest the following:

```
new_list=[]

for i in my_list:
    if i%2 == 0:
        new_list.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ways to iterate through a list in python

### Functionally

Using `map`, `filter`, `reduce` as you have in your question.

### Iterativly

With a for loop

```py
my_list = [1, 5, 4, 6, 8, 11, 3, 12]

new_list = []
for num in my_list:
    if num % 2 == 0:
         new_list.append(num)

print(new_list)
# outputs: [4,6,8,12]
```

With a list comprehension (also a for loop, but special)

```py
my_list = [1, 5, 4, 6, 8, 11, 3, 12]
new_list = [num for num in my_list if num % 2 == 0]  # compact edition
new_list = [  # more readable edition
    num
    for num in my_list
    if num % 2 == 0
]

print(new_list)
# outputs: [4,6,8,12]
```